# Htaccess Redirect Rewrite Not working together

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to remove the query strings from the urls using Htaccess, I used the following code for changing the urls, It did but after redirection to that url, I am getting 404 error.
and there is rewrite statement also if i use that only, then the new url works without 404 error, but the old urls doesnt get automatically redirected to new urls.

Here is the htaccess and url the I am modifying

```
Options FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.meenmipage.com/user/%1? [R=302,L,NC]
```

Actual Url was:

http://www.meenmipage.com/profile.php?user_id=2

and modified was:

http://www.meenmipage.com/user/2

If i remove the above code and just use the rewrite statement as like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?user_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Then the new modified url works and the old one also works

Please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `$` at the end of this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile\.php
```

because if the request URI has `user_id=2` then this condition will not match

Comment: Hello Akam, Thanks for reply.. but it doesnt worked for me also the user_id is not static its different for all users

Answer (score -1):

```
Try This !
-----------

Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{QUERY_STRING} ^user_id=([0-9]*)
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.meenmipage.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ //www.www.meenmipage.com?user_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is not a valid answer. There is no matching for `user/{id}`, and your code structure and formatting is not correct.

Comment: Hi,

This didnt worked for me, i have tried above both solutions. Please help me, its urgent and i have spent two days on this